# How to get index of a word in a string

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to run the below: -

```
def findword(string, word):
    import re
    strings=string.split()
    if word in strings:
        matches = re.finditer(string, word)
        matches_positions = [match.start() for match in matches]
        print(matches_positions)
    else:
        print("Word not found")

string=" how are you doing how do you you"
word= "you"
findword(string, word)
```

I'm only getting an empty list as result. But running the code without function gives the result of all index of the keyword. Any help would be appreciated !!!

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error.  Just where does the logic go astray, and what do you not understand about that?

Comment: @Prune Please check now

Comment: I did -- you still haven't traced anything, or checked the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
def findword(string, word):
    import re
    strings=string.split()
    if word in strings:
        matches = re.finditer(word ,string) #reversed (string, word), check documentation for correct usage
        matches_positions = [match.start() for match in matches]
        print(matches_positions)
    else:
        print("Word not found")

string=" how are you doing how do you you"
word= "you"
findword(string, word)
```

On line 5, I reversed (string, word). Please check the documentation for correct usage.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0)` takes the 1st parameter as `pattern` and `second` as `string`:

```
def findword(string, word):
    import re
    strings = string.split()
    if word in strings:
        matches = re.finditer(word, string) # see the change here
        matches_positions = [match.start() for match in matches]
        print(matches_positions)
    else:
        print("Word not found")



string=" how are you doing how do you you"
word= "you"

findword(string, word)
```

Output:

```
[9, 26, 30]
```

Comment: Much appreciated